# Pig using multiple over partition by

Tags: sql, hive, apache-pig

How can I translate the following SQL statement into pig latin?

```
select userid, siteid, eventdate, 
 count(*) over(partition by userid, siteid order by eventdate) as c, 
 rank() over (partition by userid, siteid order by eventdate) as rank
from views
```

I see that pig supports windows functions here: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html

and I can work out the first partitioning projection (I think) as

```
A = load views as (userid, siteid, eventdate); 
B = group views by (userid, siteid); 
C = foreach B { 
  C1 = order A by eventdate; 
  generate flatten(Stitch(C1, over(c1.userid, 'count'))); 
  -- how do I translate   rank() over (partition by userid, siteid order by eventdate)
   as rank
} 
D = ??? -- how do I project the fields
```

I am unclear on how to use two multiple over clauses , and unclear on how to project out the final step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [Enumerate](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/blob/master/src/java/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.java) from DataFu, it adds index to each tuple in the bag

On top of my head your code might look something like this:

```
define Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');
A = load views as (userid, siteid, eventdate); 
B = group views by (userid, siteid); 
C = foreach B { 
  C1 = order A by eventdate; 
  generate FLATTEN(group) as (userid, siteid), 
           FLATTEN(Enumerate(C1.eventdate)) as (eventdate, rank),
           COUNT(C1) as count;
} 
dump C;
```

OR

```
define Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');
A = load views as (userid, siteid, eventdate); 
B = group views by (userid, siteid); 
C = foreach B { 
  C1 = order A by eventdate; 
  generate FLATTEN(Enumerate(C1)) as (userid, siteid, eventdate, rank),
           COUNT(C1) as count;
} 
dump C;
```